# System of linear equations with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, parametric

I have this system of linear equations with parameter:

$ ax + 4y + z =0  $

$2y + 3z = 1$

$3x -cz=-2$

What I did was to put those equations into a matrix and transform that matrix it into a triangular matrix. Then I got these results on the right side:
$ \frac{-c+10}{ac-15}$, $\frac{3+(c-6)a}{2ac-30}$, $\frac{2a-6}{ac-15}$. However, I don't know what to do now.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation we get
$$z=-ax-4y$$ so we get with the third equation
$$-3ax-10y=1$$ and with the last one:
$$3x+acx+4yc=-2$$

From the second equation above $$y=-\frac{3}{10}ax-\frac{1}{10}$$ so we obtain
 finally

$$(15-ac)x=2c-1$$
Can you finish?The solution is given by $$\left\{ x=-2\,{\frac {c-5}{ac-15}},y=1/2\,{\frac {ac-6\,a+3}{ac-15}},
z=2\,{\frac {a-3}{ac-15}} \right\} 
$$
It remains to consider the case $$ac-15=0$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to solve it using Maple, so I'm trying to use matrices. Is there any ways using matrices, for an example via rank of the matrix?

Comment: It is better to use the elimination method.(so do I)

Comment: So if ac-15=0, then it has no solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) works quite well.

Our system is of the form $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ where
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
a & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 0 & -c
\end{array}\right] & \vec{x} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right] & \vec{b} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1 \\
-2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that
$$
\det(A)=2\cdot(15-ac)
$$
This means that the system has a unique solution if and only if $ac\neq 15$.

Now, assuming $ac\neq 15$, we define
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 4 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
-2 & 0 & -c
\end{array}\right] & A_2 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
a & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & -2 & -c
\end{array}\right] & A_3 &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
a & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that $A_i$ is $A$ with the $i$th column replaced by $\vec{b}$. According to Cramer's rule, the solution to the system is given by
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{\det(A_1)}{\det(A)} = \frac{2 \, {\left(c - 5\right)}}{15-ac} & y &= \frac{\det(A_2)}{\det(A)} = \frac{a {\left(c - 6\right)} + 3}{2 \, {\left(a c - 15\right)}} & z &= \frac{\det(A_3)}{\det(A)} = \frac{2 \, {\left(a - 3\right)}}{a c - 15}
\end{align*}